# node.js + express error: cannot read property 'url' of undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm fairly new to Node.js, installing it to try out the DrupalChat (v7dev) module. I believe this problem is with either node.js or express, as I am beyond the stage where the chat module's settings are loaded. I am faced with the following output when trying to start the chat server

```
Extension loaded: drupalchat_nodejs.server.extension.js
Started http server.
   info  - socket.io started

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
    at Function.handle (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:105:18)
    at Server.app (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:60:31)
    at Server.serverListening (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/policyfile/lib/server.js:136:16)
    at Server.g (events.js:154:14)
    at Server.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at Array.1 (net.js:710:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:40)
```

I remember when express installed, it gave a warning like ".... bugs['web'] should probably be bugs['url']"  (I can't remember the prefix)

So is it that the server is trying to read an (API?) variable 'url' but its currently 'web'?

I have all the modules up to date, is it that I should downgrade? Or is there some way of working around this using another module?

EDIT:
line 201 is the last very line (delete authenticatedClients[authData.authToken];)... I just added to whole function for proper context

```
var authenticateClientCallback = function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) {
    console.log("Error with authenticate client request:", error);
    return;
  }
  if (response.statusCode == 404) {
    if (settings.debug) {
      console.log('Backend authentication url not found, full response info:', response);
    }
    else {
      console.log('Backend authentication url not found.');
    }
    return;
  }

  var authData = false;
  try {
    authData = JSON.parse(body);
  }
  catch (exception) {
    console.log('Failed to parse authentication message:', exception);
    if (settings.debug) {
      console.log('Failed message string: ' + body);
    }
    return;
  }
  if (!checkServiceKey(authData.serviceKey)) {
    console.log('Invalid service key "', authData.serviceKey, '"');
    return;
  }
  if (authData.nodejsValidAuthToken) {
    if (settings.debug) {
      console.log('Valid login for uid "', authData.uid, '"');
    }
    setupClientConnection(authData.clientId, authData, authData.contentTokens);
    authenticatedClients[authData.authToken] = authData;
  }
  else {
    console.log('Invalid login for uid "', authData.uid, '"');
    delete authenticatedClients[authData.authToken];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show node.js:201 or maybe a bit more.

Comment: I added it in, now I'm wondering if its a non-required setting (serviceKey) in the DrupalChat config that the developer probably made required but didn't reflect in his code/comments

Comment: v7 is not stable, you may find something here : http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupalchat?status=All&categories=All

Comment: hey yeah, I looked through it, there is a lot of documentation lacking for the drupal 7 module and using node.js, I'm slowly playing around with configuration variables now... I guess I'll mark that comment as right... don't know how much more time to dedicate to this module in it's current state

Comment: @racar can you put that comment as an answer for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As requested,

The v7 chat module from drupal is not stable. You should not use it in production.

Check bugs : http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupalchat?status=All&categories=All

Check forums : http://drupalchat7.botskool.co.in/?q=forum

Still looking for a new maintener:
"New maintainer wanted - please ping beejeebus if you're interested!".

Answer (score 1):

Per @thesnufkin's post, looks like the underlying express version currently pulled is not stable. Roll back to 2.5.9 and you should be good to go:

npm uninstall express
npm install express@2.5.9

Answer (score 0):

nodejs module has this issue, so I don't think its related to the drupalchat server specifically. Here is the issue for that: http://drupal.org/node/1537702

Comment: hey, thanks for pointing me to that, I'll monitor that thread... you're quick on the draw, that issue was only raised today! :)

Answer (score 0):

The option to use node.js as backend in DrupalChat is currently under development. It also depends when (date on which) you downloaded the DrupalChat since the dev code is updated everyday, if new code is committed.

Please raise an issue for the same at this link - http://drupal.org/project/issues/drupalchat?status=All&categories=All.

Thanks,

darklrd

Comment: P.S. - Also, the DrupalChat module doesn't require a new maintainer as indicated in the currently marked answer. It is under active development.